# WPF Tab to Window

Tags: .net, wpf

I am building a WPF (.Net 5) app. I am using tabs. Is it possible to take a tab and "bust" it out into its own window? I am asking because this would allow the viewing of two tabs sort of side by side.

If any of you have a better way to be able to view tabs side by side, I would love to hear.

The code...

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{ Binding DetailViewModels }" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                TabStripPlacement="Top">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource closeButtonStyle}"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="x" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

What I do to create the tabs is have a command that creates a detailViewModel that gets added to the DetailViewModels observable collection. The detail view is just a user control.

Comment: Can you please show one of the tabs xmal?

Comment: @ClayHess Based on the code you've provided, I've assumed that the `SelectedDetailViewModel` can be passed to the sub-window. Check the update I made to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the tab's content out to a new window and vise versa, then you can try to create a new `UserControl` with the content you want inside, put that `UserControl` inside both the window and the tab, and then create a `ViewModel` to be used as a shared `DataContext` of them both.

Not sure if this is the best way to do it though.

---

#### Update

Here is what I mean using the sample code you provided:

In your App.xaml:

```xml
<Application ...
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModelsNamespace"
             ...>

    <Application.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource closeButtonStyle}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="x" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </Application.Resources>
    
</Application>
```

In your Main Window:

```xml
<Window ...>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{ Binding DetailViewModels }" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                TabStripPlacement="Top"/>
    
</Window>
```

In your tab-viewing sub window:

```xml
<Window ...>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedDetailViewModel}" />
</Window>
```

This way you have a `DataTemplate` defined for your `DetailViewModel` in your application resources, so whenever you are binding it, it will be viewed using this `DataTemplate`.

Thus, all that you need to do is to bind the collection `DetailViewModels` to the `TabControl.ItemsSource` in your main window and bind the `SelectedDetailViewModel` to the `ContentControl` in the sub-window, and both of them will view the same thing.

And if the tab's content grew larger, you can place it in a `UserControl` and use it for the `DataTemplate` instead, as I suggested earlier:

The `UserControl`, say "MyUserControl.xaml":

```xml
<UserControl ...>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

        <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource closeButtonStyle}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="x" />
    </StackPanel>
    
    ....
    ....

</UserControl>
```

And in App.xaml:

```xml
<Application ...
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModelsNamespace"
             ...>

    <Application.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailViewModel}">
            <local:MyUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </Application.Resources>
    
</Application>
```